# Centralized all functions/ methods [Android in Java]

Tags: android, function

I would like to centralize most of my common functions and those can just be called anytime anywhere. Is that possible to do that?

For example:

```
public void showError(final String Error_Msg) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(common_provider.this, Error_Msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use static functions.
Create Class, for example `CommonFucntions.class`

## CommonFunctions.class

```
public class CommonFunctions {

    public static void showError(final Activity activity, final String Error_Msg) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(activity, Error_Msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

And then, whereever you want, you can use this function, by calling `CommonFunctions.showError(this, "Sample error");`

Comment: No, you try then you will know. It doesn't allow you to have runOnUiThread and even a Toast Msg. Please have a try on it. E.g. define the class and call the function from MainActivity

Comment: You updated the definition but not the calling statement [parameters]. BTW, I still get java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Extend Application class for that: https://www.mobomo.com/2011/05/how-to-use-application-object-of-android/